# How can I create a synchronous wrapper around an async callback in C++?

Tags: c++, asynchronous, callback, synchronization, asynccallback

I'm working with the [libportal](https://libportal.org/) library from C++ to improve the [Flatpak](https://www.flatpak.org/) support of an already existing application, and I've run into the problem that many of the APIs exposed by libportal are asynchronous, but the codebase I'm working with is written in such a way that it assumes the relevant operations to be synchronous. I could, of course, refactor the code to support asynchronous operations, but this would require a significant changes to the application's codebase, and it would bing no clear benefit as for the purposes I need libportal it does not matter that the main thread gets blocked. I have talked to one libportal maintainer, and he said that he is not interested in adding a synchronous variant of the API I want to use ([`xdp_portal_open_file`](https://libportal.org/method.Portal.open_file.html)), and instead suggests I just make a synchronous wrapper myself, which finally brings me to my question:

How can I go about making a synchronous wrapper for a callback-based asynchronous function in C++? In this case, the callback is a [`GAsyncReadyCallback`](https://docs.gtk.org/gio/callback.AsyncReadyCallback.html) from [Gio 2.0](https://docs.gtk.org/gio/index.html).

Comment: The short answer is: you figure out how to do it, for each particular use case. There is no universal, paint-by-numbers, recipe for doing this with every such library in the world. You sit down, go through the library's reference material, until you fully understand how it works. Once it is fully understood how the library goes about its business, it should be clear how to implement an alternative API wrapper for it.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik In that case, would it be preferable to rephrase it such that it asks how to do this in the context of libportal specifically? I don't mean to sound like I'm expecting someone else to do the work for me, but I'm not even sure how to start here. And no, this is not something I'm getting paid to do.

Answer (score 2):

I created an example for you using condition variables.
I don't have your framework so I used std::async to simulate an asynchronous call.

What the example basically is does start the asynchronous call, let the callback set a signal when the asynchronous function is done. The calling thread will then block until the flag is set (without spending any CPU time in the meantime).

```
#include <chrono>
#include <future>
#include <iostream>
#include <mutex>
#include <condition_variable>
#include <thread>

// use a condition variable, a mutex and a flag to build a synchronization point.
// condition variables are more like a signal between threads then a real variable!
// and are used a lot to do inter-thread signaling, because the avoid busy loops
class synchronization_point_t
{
public:
    void set()
    {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock{ m_mtx };
        m_flag = true;
        m_cv.notify_all();
    }

    void wait()
    {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock{ m_mtx };
        m_cv.wait(lock, [&] {return m_flag; });
    }

private:
    std::mutex m_mtx;
    std::condition_variable m_cv;
    bool m_flag{ false };
};

//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------

void callback(void* userdata)
{
    std::cout << "callback setting synchronization point signal\n";
    auto synchronization_point = reinterpret_cast<synchronization_point_t*>(userdata);
    synchronization_point->set();
}

void async_fn(void* userdata)
{
    std::cout << "async_fn starting\n";

    // simulate some work here
    for (std::size_t n = 0; n < 10; ++n)
    {
        std::cout << ".";
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(100));
    }
    std::cout << "\n";

    std::cout << "async_fn calling callback\n";
    callback(userdata);
    std::cout << "async_fn done\n";
}


void fn()
{
    std::cout << "fn() creating a synchronization point\n";
    synchronization_point_t synchronization_point;

    std::cout << "fn() calling the asynchronous variant\n";
    auto future = std::async(std::launch::async, [&]
    {
        async_fn(reinterpret_cast<void*>(&synchronization_point));
    });

    // this will wait until the function has called the callbacks
    std::cout << "fn() waiting for the asynchronous call to complete\n";
    synchronization_point.wait();
    std::cout << "fn() done\n";
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << "main calling synchronous version of fn()\n";
    fn();
    std::cout << "main done\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I can't suggest an edit because the queue is full, but at least with GCC 11 this only compiles if you also `#include <thread>`. Aside from that, thanks! I'm digging into it to make sure I understand it first, but I'll probably accept this as the answer to my question when I'm done.

Comment: Condition variables are a bit of a thing when you first see them, don't hesitate to ask questions.  I added the '''#include <thread>'''. Usually I Compile on MSVC/C++17 (or C++20 settings)